# Fast memcpy in C#

Tags: c#, performance, memcpy

I want to write a C# method with prototype like this:

```
void memcpy(byte[] dst, int dstOffset, byte[] src, int srcOffset, int len);
```

I have 2 options for this method:

**1.**

```
void memcpy(byte[] dst, int dstOffset, byte[] src, int srcOffset, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        dst[dstOffset + i] = src[srcOffset + i];
    }
}
```

**2.**

```
void memcpy(byte[] dst, int dstOffset, byte[] src, int srcOffset, int len)
{
    IntPtr intPtr = getIntPtr(dst, dstOffset);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(src, srcOffset, intPtr, len);
}

IntPtr getIntPtr(byte[] buffer, int offset)
{
    IntPtr intPtr;
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* p1 = buffer)
        {
            byte* p2 = p1 + offset;
            intPtr = (IntPtr)p2;
        }
    }
    return intPtr;
}
```

**Questions:**

A. I guess option 2 is faster than option 1, is it right?

B. Is there another faster method?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are in just as good a position to **test this** as any of us are. If not better, because the code is already in front of you.

Comment: Bad question. Firstly, "is it <question>" is usually bad here. This is a speed issue.. benchmark it yourself. Secondly.. they are all pretty much the same.

Comment: @Jonathon: Testing is unlikely to discover the race condition (wrt garbage collection).

Comment: @Simon: This is not a speed issue.  It is a correctness issue.

Comment: @BenVoigt Fair enough - but I was responding to his questions. To be honest I didn't really even look at the code. He never asked if his implementation was correct.

Comment: @BenVoigt "I guess option 2 is faster than option 1. Is it right?". That is a speed question/issue.. hence "benchmark it yourself".

Comment: @Simon: All optimization problems are chiefly correctness issues and performance only secondarily.  If correctness is not required, I replace your entire program with an empty file, which I assure you is *much* faster.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart: "never asked if his implementation was correct" -> Because I already tested them with my C# app, it runs correctly, so far I haven't seen any problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option #2 is broken, since you're using the pointer after the object it points to is no longer fixed.  Pointers obtained within a `fixed` block may only be used inside that same `fixed` block.  And it seems like you should have used [`Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.unsafeaddrofpinnedarrayelement.aspx) anyway (and use it only inside a `fixed` block pinning the array).

Have a look at [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx).