# Is it possible to copy class fields with unsafe

Tags: c#, unsafe

I have two classes

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 12, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
unsafe class Dto
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int B;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int C;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public int D;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 12, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
unsafe class Model
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int B;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int C;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public int D;
}
```

Is there the way to copy data from fields from instance of DTO o instance of Model?
For a single field I have following code

```
var a1 = new Dto { B = 10, C = 20, D = 30 };
var a2 = new Model();

unsafe
{
     fixed (int* pa1 = &(a1.B))
     {
          fixed (int* pa2 = &(a2.B))
          {
               *pa2 = *pa1;
          }
     }
 }
```

Does C# provide similar method to copy whole object? Copy field-by-field is not desirable due to high performance environment.

Comment: You mean, like a [c memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) ?

Comment: These should be plain structs.  No point in doing anything unsafe, you can simply assign.  Value types exist to make code faster, use them.

Comment: "Copy field-by-field is not desirable due to high performance environment." ==> Have you measured it? Any actual performance issue?

Comment: [Say no to public fields](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Even in structs?  I've never heard that argument made.

Comment: This has been answered already on this site: [Fast memcpy in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963001/fast-memcpy-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @recursive Come on, I don't see structs here? am I missing something? and what's the excuse for structs? Educate me please..

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: My mistake.  I thought I saw structs defined, not classes.  It is common to use public fields in structs.  I'm not sure if there is an excuse, but in many cases, the benefits provided by properties are not needed, particularly in immutable data structures.

Comment: My mistake is to show such small classes. Actually, it just an example. Of course copy 3 ints filed-by-filed is good. MyBut what if there are number of classes in DTO and Model with number of fields? Wouldn't it faster to copy memory from one object to another?

Answer (score 2):

Your main concern is performance. If you copy field-by-field, this will translate to 6 `mov` instructions. It is very hard to make it faster then this.

Using pointers does not reduce the number of instructions required. Why would it? You still need the same assignments.

Calling `memcpy` involves far more overhead then the trivial 6 `mov` instructions.

So you should write the "naive" three assignments using safe managed code to get optimal performance. In fact, copying this 12-byte object is so cheap that I doubt your performance concerns are valid. I doubt this will show up on any profile.

For copy performance it does not matter whether you use `class` or `struct`. But `struct` has certain performance benefits due to other differences. You might want to investigate them.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to memcpy in C# is Buffer.BlockCopy, though it is designed for arrays.

This is an [interesting article](http://code4k.blogspot.com/2010/10/high-performance-memcpy-gotchas-in-c.html) on the topic.

I think though that if you were to simplify your code, remove the unsafe and just use plain structs maybe with conversion operators, you would be very surprised by the performance.

Something like;

```
   public struct Model
   {
      public int B;
      public int C;
      public int D;

      public Model(Dto dto)
      {
         B = dto.B;
         C = dto.C;
         D = dto.D;
      }

      static public implicit operator Model(Dto dto)
      {
         return new Model(dto);
      }
   }
```

would allow you to just say ...

```
     Dto a1 = new Dto { B = 10, C = 20, D = 30 };

     Model m = a1;
```

Comment: I'm not fully described my question. sorry. Copy data from an existing instance to an existing instans also the part of the goal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Could you rephrase your comment?

Comment: The main goal is to achive reuse of objects. I have a pool of the DTOs and a pool of the Model's objects. When receiving a DTO, I have to copy it to Model object, and release it to the pool.

Answer (score -1):

If both structs have same layout you can just cast pointer and assign like this:

```
var a1 = new Dto { B = 10, C = 20, D = 30 };
var a2 = new Model();

unsafe
{
     fixed (Dto * pa1 = &(a1))
     {
          fixed (Model* pa2 = &(a2))
          {
               *pa2 = *(Model*)pa1;
          }
     }
 }
```